# jQuery pull menu event

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have a responsive menu in place for window size that is less than 690.  When the screen is resized, the pull menu appears with a simple Menu button.  I have a slideToggle() working great, but can't seem to figure out how to collapse the menu once a link has been selected, WITHOUT it affecting window sizes that are greater than 690.  Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var pull = $('#pull');
                menu = $('nav ul');
                w = $(window).width();
                link = $('nav ul li');
                menuHeight = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
                menu = $('nav ul');
                link = $('nav ul li a');

            if(w > 690 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            } 
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to the click event on the menu items like so:

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 690)
        menu.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I have tried this, but this will also cause the menu to toggle in a screen size larger than 690.  I tried throwing it into the if statement, but no luck

Comment: @Ben Updated to check for window size